# How to reduce boiler plate code in below use case

Tags: java, kotlin, software-design, code-reuse

What was the best solution to make use of reusability in below use case.
I was trying to clear the strings whenever user clicks on button by using below function.
I tried many ways and haven't found any reliable solution.

```
private void clearFields(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        boardId = "";
        stateId = "";
        cityId = "";
        schoolId = "";
        classId = "";
        orientationId = "";
        studentTypeId = "";
    } else if (i == 1) {
        stateId = "";
        cityId = "";
        schoolId = "";
        classId = "";
        orientationId = "";
        studentTypeId = "";
    } else if (i == 2) {
        cityId = "";
        schoolId = "";
        classId = "";
        orientationId = "";
        studentTypeId = "";
    } else if (i == 3) {
        schoolId = "";
        classId = "";
        orientationId = "";
        studentTypeId = "";
    } else if (i == 4) {
        classId = "";
        orientationId = "";
        studentTypeId = "";
    } else if (i == 5) {
        orientationId = "";
        studentTypeId = "";
    } else if (i == 6) {
        studentTypeId = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do inline checks... Something like: `boardId = (i == 0) ? "" : boardId; stateId = (i == 0) || (i == 1) ? "" : stateId;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you truly want to do this via an index.  If so, then I would argue that the cleanest and simplest way would be to use a switch without breaks.  There are other tricky ways to do this, but I try to avoid "tricky" wherever possible.

```
public class Test {
    
    private void clearFields(final int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                boardId = "";
            case 1:
                stateId = "";
            case 2:
                cityId = "";
            case 3:
                schoolId = "";
            case 4:
                classId = "";
            case 5:
                orientationId = "";
            case 6:
                studentTypeId = "";
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("Invalid index supplied");
        }
    }

    

    private String boardId;
    private String stateId;
    private String cityId;
    private String schoolId;
    private String classId;
    private String orientationId;
    private String studentTypeId;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Test test = new Test();
        test.setValues();
        test.printValues();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            test.clearFields(i);
            test.printValues();
            test.setValues();
        }
    }

    private void setValues() {
        boardId = "boardId";
        stateId = "stateId";
        cityId = "cityId";
        schoolId = "schoolId";
        classId = "classId";
        orientationId = "orientationId";
        studentTypeId = "studentTypeId";
    }

    private void printValues() {
        System.out.println("boardId = " + boardId);
        System.out.println("stateId = " + stateId);
        System.out.println("cityId = " + cityId);
        System.out.println("schoolId = " + schoolId);
        System.out.println("classId = " + classId);
        System.out.println("orientationId = " +orientationId);
        System.out.println("studentTypeId = " + studentTypeId);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**
We have only a small code snip in isolation to look at.  I feel that the code I show is the cleanest possible way to do what you are asking.  Having said that, it's likely that the entire design needs to be rethought such that you aren't using an index in this manner at all.  Having said *that*, I will be the first to admit that sometimes one takes shortcuts in some corners of one's code when one is reasonably sure that corner won't change.

It's at least possible that I would write the precise code you have if I felt strongly that the code would not need maintenance.  I can always refactor it later if that assumption proves wrong.  That's why I say that I'm assuming you truly want to do what you are asking.  There's no way for us to know your requirements - so there's no way for us to know how much a problem "maintainability" is going to be.

Besides which, going back and refactoring your own code will probably teach you more about clean design than anything I could think of to say...

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful about reducing boilerplate code. It is a good idea and both answers are pretty nice. What you need to consider is (since you have tagged it with software-design tag):

1. Is this actual code? Or just example? If latter, you would find refactoring code to be much more difficult to *maintain*.
2. If you do decide to refactor this, I would prefer what @Chris Parker mentioned, specifically, "If so, then I would argue that the cleanest and simplest way would be to use a switch without breaks". But it would be a nightmare for someone who will deal with it later. The best way to avoid that to certain degree is to use `enum` for switch\case.

Comment: Absolutely, 200% agree.  That's why I prefaced my answer with "I'm assuming...".